# KML better approach than standard google api for large number of markers

Tags: java, javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Developing a google map which is powered by an underlying report. The report is dynamic and can be changed by the end user. In addition users have the ability to set threshholds on the map which requires re-rendering of all markers on the map. I have been able to limit the number of rows being renderd to 600 but each row will have; 1 polygon, 3 other markers. This is causing degrading performance. I am working on optimizing the java script which is being generated, but I fear that it will always be slow.

With that said I thought about investigating the possibility of using java generated kml files. I found an API which may handle this generation, JAK. Is using KML files which are generated at runtime for an application a better approach than native javascript/jquery? Does anyone have experience performing this with java?

```
client side marker

     var cir = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(l.lat, l.lng),
                map: map,
                icon: icons[l.type].simple


KML layer
  kmllayyer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
                    url: kmlLayerURL,
                    preserveViewport: true
                });
```

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. It sounds like you have about 2400 markers. You are currently reading a report from JavaScript and calling Google Maps API's to add the markers.  I believe your question is whether Google Maps would perform better if you generated all the points in an external process (possibly implemented in Java) and then had Google Maps load the KML.

Answer (score 0):

No, if the degraded performance is caused by the large number of markers (approx 2400) you should not experience better performance if those markers are loaded from KML vs API calls.

It is possible that your report parsing code is inefficient and leaking memory.  If so, moving that code out of the browser and into another process would free browser memory and client side processor cycles.

You haven't provided enough information or details to answer your question.

Comment: Performance will be greatly increased if using KML layers as opposed to client side markers or polygons.

Comment: Is your comment based on experience/benchmarks?  Please provide additional information! In either case there are still the same number of markers.  Why would markers built by google's javascript parsing your kml perform better than markers you build directly?

Comment: Googles javascript doesn't parse the KML. It renderes the KML as a layer. This is based off experience. You cannot renderd 10,000 markers using client side api. But if you have 10,000 markers defined in a KML file you can render it. See above.